How to break out of multiple nested loops in JavaScript?
I’m working on a JavaScript program that involves multiple nested loops, and I need a way to break out of all the loops when a specific condition is met. Here’s a simplified example of what I’m trying to do:
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        console.log(`i: ${i}, j: ${j}`);
        if (i === 2 && j === 3) {
            // Break out of both loops here
        }
    }
}

In this example, if i === 2 and j === 3, I want to exit both loops immediately. I understand that break only exits the innermost loop, so I’m unsure how to handle this scenario effectively.
What is the best way to break out of nested loops in JavaScript? Are there any performance implications to the suggested approaches?
Thank you for your help!

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let breakOuter = false;
    for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        console.log(`i: ${i}, j: ${j}`);
        if (i === 2 && j === 3) {
            // Break out of both loops here
            breakOuter = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (breakOuter) {
        break;
    }
}

